# Returning float pointer to char vector data read from file

Tags: c++, casting, io

The data in Resource are read from a fistream using read and since read takes a char array I store it in a vector.. When I load the data onto the GPU I would only need the char pointer to the data.. but eg. if I need to calculate the boundingbox of the vertex buffer I would need to have the data as a float.. is this an ok way to do it? Should I return the reference to the vector in GetDataChar() instead?

```
class Resource
{
protected:
    const std::vector<char>& GetDataRef() const
    {
        return m_data;
    }
private:
    std::vector<char> m_data;
}

class VertexBuffer : public Resource
{
public:
    const char* GetDataChar() const
    {
        return &GetDataRef()[0];
    }

    const float* GetDataFloat() const
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<float*>(&GetDataRef()[0]);
    }
}

class IndexBuffer : public Resource
{
public:
    const char* GetDataChar() const
    {
        return &GetDataRef()[0];
    }

    const int* GetDataInt() const
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<int*>(&GetDataRef()[0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ standard doesn't really say anything about this: externalizing objects, even of built-in types, and reading them back may work or may not work. In practise it tends to work about it generally a bad idea: what starts out a quick way of doing things often quickly becomes used in many places (after all it "works") and effectively restricts usage of the approach to one platform. I have worked on more than project where there is a strong dependency on 32 bit words with a certain Endianess. The fact that contemporary system tend to 64 bit words and popular (and thus cheap and powerful) CPUs a different Endianess effectively means that these projects are restricted to relatively expensive machines which are on top of it abused to run in 32 bit compatibility mode.

That said, it works in practise despite the standard note really making any guarantees. However, the approach you have chosen is bound **not** to work too well: there are effectively no alignment constraints on `char`, i.e. the `std::vector<char>` may allocate memory and happy put e.g. a 32 bit word in front of it, if nothing else for its own entertainment. This would mean that the words you want to load are not properly aligned and either won't be loaded at all or would be loaded in slow-motion. That is, you want your `std::vector<T>` hold objects with the maximum alignment requirement (e.g. some 16 byte word to cope with 128 bit words) and cast the address to this type to `char`. This, of course, still means that the data needs to be dumped in exactly the same format as is used on the machine. If possible I would try to avoid this approach.

Comment: Hmm.. I've read your answer a couple of times, but I dont get it :p When I read the data I use: m_data.resize(filesize); filestream.read(&m_data[0], fileSize); I've seen this done in quiet a few places..

Comment: The short version: don't use unformatted binary I/O if you can do it differently. If you unformatted binary I/O is your only options, make sure your objects are properly aligned: the array of `char`s in a `std::vector<char>` is bound not to be properly aligned. If I talk in terms you don't understand I **strongly** recommend you **don't** use unformatted binary I/O! It is quite possible that you didn't want this answer but saying "it works" (which seems to be the answer you want to get) would be wrong. If you clarify which part you don't get I'd be happy to explain.

Comment: Code for what? For binary formatting of floating point values? Not easily. This non-trivial to do correct and fast in general. Depending on the data to be formatted it may be unnecessary to format floating point values, however. For example, I have written code for encoding and decoding of decimal values (e.g. using FAST encoding). It is simpler than writing floating point values but still non-trivial.

Comment: "externalizing objects, even of built-in types, and reading them back may work or may not work." what do you mean by externalizing objects and reading them back?

Comment: Do you mean that chars might be stored like this in memmory? c=char e= empty and that this is 32bits in total?  |c|e|e|e|

Comment: No I don't just want a "yes it works" answer.. well that would be the easiest :) But I'm doing this to learn..

Comment: Essentially I mean "take the bytes and stuff them into something". I can be a file, a socket, etc. When you get the same bytes back there is no guarantee to that you can directly interpret them as the things they were. The standard only mandates that you can `memcpy()` or `memmove()` PODs to other PODs. It generally works if you put the bytes back into appropriately aligned objects - assuming you run the same program on the same architecture.

Comment: The main partical issue is alignment. If you restore objects a float e.g. to an odd address you will [normally] get a bus error when you try to access it (i.e. the CPU complained that it was asked to access value at an address it doesn't support). The fundamental built-in types are required to use all bits, i.e. the can't have any holes. However, the exact layout even of the fundamental types definitely depends on the platform e.g. different Endianess causes problems. floating point types also have an internal structure which I think can go beyond Endianess although IEEE-754 defines all bits.

Comment: So if I write a float to a file it might be stored |f0|f1|f2|f3| where the f's are the float bytes (taking up 32 bits).. now when I read it from the file, the alignment can cause it to be stored |f0|e|e|e|f1|e|e|e|f2|e|e|e|f3| where e is empty or just some random data and now taking up 128 bits.. Am I getting there?

Comment: No, this can't really happen. Alignment is essentially about the start address: if the start address of a four byte word isn't divisible by 4 most CPUs won't give the word the love it wants. They would typically cause a signal and terminate the program. If the words you want to read are bigger (e.g. 16 byte) you might need bigger alignment there is a limit on the alignment requirements, however, which is often the same as the size of cache lines. When you allocate an array of `T` objects, the run-time will arrange for the address to be suitable for `T`s but not necessarily for bigger types.

Comment: When you move files between platforms, you may have issues with Endianess, i.e. an integer which is stored as |i0|i1|i2|i3| on one platform may be stored as |i3|i2|i1|i0| on another platform (conceptually, the bit indices also change but you can't tell these apart). If you have floating points the bytes may be entirely different between platforms.

Comment: ah.. right.. what if I use vector<float> m_data(filesize); filestream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&m_data[0]), filesize); ..this shouldn't be a problem right?

Comment: This should be OK if you only want to access a sequence of `float`s. However, if you e.g. want to create an SSE "`float` vector" this won't be good enough: for these you need to have 16 byte alignment. If you want to pass the obect to a GPU you probably need similar alignment but I haven't used these, yet.

Comment: Do you know of any good articles or book(chapters) explaining this stuff? I'm still confused on this and on how I should implement my stuff...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know off-hand of any resource which pulls all of this together. The various details are sprinkled over all kinds of resources but I wouldn't be able to quote any off-hand either.